# Why is iAd Workbench completely broken?

Tags: app-store-connect

Since the release of iOS 9, I can't view my ad revenue. Every time I try to pull up iAd Workbench, I get this message:

[image: screen-cap]

It looks like a Java error. It happens on my phone as well.

- Safari on a Mac. Yosemite 10.10.5
- Mobile Safari on my iOS 9-running iPhone 6
- Google Chrome on 64-bit Windows 7

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

If you have that many browsers failing, you should contact Apple Developer support to have them check on things.

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/

The [system status show no outage](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) so you'll need someone on the inside to point out what you're doing wrong or fix what they're doing wrong (other than still using Tomcat, I suppose).